# "Bootmgr is missing...." Upon reboot

Tags: installation, dual-boot, hard-drive, boot-failure, external-hdd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install/running ubuntu on extarnal HDD with a windows laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118044/install-running-ubuntu-on-extarnal-hdd-with-a-windows-laptop)

Ill take you through the steps I did. Sorry if this question has already been resolved, I'm new to Ubuntu and forums in general.

I have 2 internal HDDs in my computer, both with Win7. One HDD is my mothers, the other is mine. I did this because she didn't want my games on her computer, and my PCs motherboard took a crap on me, so I set up a dual boot.

I also have an external HDD. This is what I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 on.
I formatted the drive by right clicking it, then selecting "Format". It is now in NTSF format. I downloaded the Windows installer, ran it, and selected "I:/" (my externl hdd) as the install location. The download and installation ran smoothly, and it gave me the reboot prompt. I selected "Reboot now" and my PC rebooted. I was then interrupted by the "Bootmgr is missing. Press CTRL + ALT + DEL TO REBOOT" message.

NOTE: I would like to use my HDD for a FULL Ubuntu installation, not the Live (i think thats what its called). I want all my files and settings from Ubuntu saved to the External drive as if it was my only drive.

If you need more information just ask.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I was then interrupted by the "Bootmgr is missing. Press CTRL + ALT + DEL TO REBOOT" message.

You get this because Wubi depends on the Windows boot manager to add its boot entry and since you don't have Windows installed there (on your external drive) you  don't have BOOTMGR.

What you can do is to Format the external drive and Install Ubuntu there, partition it in ext4 and make an Ubuntu LiveCD or LiveUSB and off you go.

Comment: Ok Thanks. Do I have to re-format it even though I already have Ubuntu installed on it? It took about 4 hours to format the first time, and it only had about 3 mb of files on it. I really don't feel like going through all that again. 
Sorry for all the questions. I'm quite new to all of this.

Isn't the LiveUSB the portable version of Ubuntu? 

What is Wubi?