# Another BOOTMGR is missing question

Tags: dual-boot, startup, restart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Bootmgr is missing…” Upon reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196135/bootmgr-is-missing-upon-reboot)

I downloaded an OS uninstaller, and uninstalled Windows and all its backups. I just want Ubuntu on my laptop. So when I turned it back on, Bootmgr is missing press any key to restart. Any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing you can do is search for repair option in ubuntu live-cd/usb. Otherwise go for ubuntu installation.